# 'Sorry to Interrupt' error popup in lightning experience error in all the sandboxes. What this error mean?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I am facing this error after login and whenever I try to do anything after login such tab click or user icon click. 
I cleared browser history and data of chrome but still same issue.[image: igh]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with WalkMe (https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pzVgQAI). If you can, disabling the Chrome Extension should prevent the pop-up error (not ideal, but you can still get your job done).

There's one suggested fix from two weeks ago one the thread linked above - suggesting you need to publish some 'global settings' to Production? https://support.walkme.com/knowledge-base/how-to-publish-global-settings/